# Openerp roster cancellation and re-assigning functions

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to write a new Roster module with Openerp 7.0 and had an issue with when cancelling a roster from one employee and allocate that particular roster to another (substitute) employee. 
Following is what I did...

my **Time slot definition class**

```
 class roster_time(osv.osv):

    _name="roster.time"
    _description = "To create roster time slot"

    _columns={
           'roster_id':fields.integer('Roster ID'),
           'start_time': fields.char('Start Time',required=True),
           'end_time':fields.char('End Time',required=True),
           'rostertype':fields.many2one('roster.type','roster','Roster Time'),
           'name':fields.char('Roster Time'),

           }


roster_time()
```

**Roster Definition class**

```
class roster_type(osv.osv):

_name="roster.type"
_description = "To create roster type for each department"

_columns={


    'name': fields.char('Roster type'),
           'roster':fields.one2many('roster.time','rostertype','Time Slot'),

           'allocation_id':fields.many2one('roster.allocation','Roster ID'),
           'roster_time':fields.many2one('roster.time','Slot'),
          'roster_end':fields.related('roster.time','roster_start',type='char',string='End Time'),
           'allocation_start_day':fields.date('Start Date' ),
           'allocation_end_day':fields.date('End Date'),
           'department_id':fields.many2one('hr.department','Department',required=True),



           }


roster_time()
```

**Roster allocation class**

```
    class roster_allocation(osv.osv):

     _name="roster.allocation"
     _description ="Allocate rosters on employees"


     _columns={

         'emp_id':fields.many2one('hr.employee','Employee',required=True),
         'department_id':fields.many2one('hr.department','Department',required=True),
         #'roster':fields.many2one('roster.type','roster', 'Roster ID'),
         'roster_linked_ids':fields.one2many('roster.type','allocation_id','Roster Linked Ids'),

         'roster_type':fields.related('roster.type','department_id', type='char', string='Roster Type'),
         'roster_time':fields.char('Take the related field  roster_time.name'),
         'monthly allocation':fields.char('Month')   ,

         'roster_rest_allocation':fields.one2many('roster.rest.days','roster_id','Rest Days'),
         'roster_substitute':fields.one2many('roster.substitution','allocation_id','Substitution'),



            }



roster_allocation()
```

**Roster Cancellation class**

```
class roster_substitution(osv.osv):
    _name="roster.substitution"
    _description="Substituting employees "
    _columns={
             'allocation_id':fields.many2one('roster.allocation','Allocation'),
             'employee':fields.many2one('hr.employee','Employee'),
             'sub_employee':fields.many2one('hr.employee','Employee'),
             'time_slot':fields.many2one('roster.time','Roster'),
             'roster_day':fields.date('Day'),
             'reason':fields.text('Reason'),
             'department_id':fields.many2one('hr.department','Department'),


             }
roster_substitution()
```

"I have removed all the validations and other calculations for the occasion."

My issues are
1). In **Roster cancellations** class, Once I select department I need to load roster time slots automatically in particular field as well as, once I select one time slot from it and the date , I need to show the allocated employee on that read only field

2). Once I select the substitute employee, I need to add the time slot of the cancellation requested employee's time slot in this substitute employee and in original employee i need to show it in different color.

Please help me with this, even though I tried to that on change functions for the 1st question I don't  have any idea about doing the 2) one which is most important.

please help me to solve this.

this is the function I tried with but I know it's wrong

```
 def allocation_substitute(self,cr,uid,ids,roster_day,context=None):
        sub_day=vals.get(roster_day)
        sub_time_slot=vals.get(time_slot)

        allocation_obj=self.pool.get('roster.allocation')
        original_employee_id =  allocation_obj.browse(cr,uid, values['emp_id']).id
        original_employee_roster=allocation_obj.browse(cr,uid, original_employee_id).roster_type

        values={'emp_id':'employee',
                'department_id':'department_id',
                }
        allocation_id=allocation_obj.create(cr, uid, value, context=context)
```